# Example of inner product as matrix multiplication

Tags: inner-products

Can anyone please give an example for the following:[image]

If I take $B=\{[1\ 0],[0\ 1]\} \implies M=I$. If $x=[1 \ 2], y=[3 \ 4]$, then $\langle x,y\rangle =11$. $[y]^H=[3 \ 4]^T$. But $[3 \ 4]^T M=[3 \ 4]^TI=[3 \ 4]^T \ne \langle x,y\rangle$? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It's the transpose of the (column) vector of coordinates relative to the basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've calculated $y^H M$ instead of $y^H Mx$.

Comment: Thanks. $y^HMx=y^HIx=y^Hx=<x,y>$ Got it now.

Answer (score 1):

According to the argument you shared $M = [\mu_{lk}]$ where $\mu_{lk}=  \langle v_k , v_l\rangle$. Since you chose your $B$ to be as such, then
\begin{equation}
 v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
  1 \\ 0
 \end{bmatrix}
\quad 
\text{ and } 
\quad 
 v_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
  0 \\ 1
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
 M
 =
 \begin{bmatrix}
  \langle v_1,v_1\rangle & \langle v_1,v_2\rangle\\
  \langle v_2,v_1\rangle & \langle v_2,v_2\rangle
 \end{bmatrix}
 =
 \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks @J.G. .. somehow i always forget how to insert those left and right angle brackets